# Use service inside SDR projection

Tags: spring-data-rest, spring-projections

I have an entity class Person with uuid column. I have an external rest service(ExternalRestService) where I could fetch information by mentioned uuid column.
I want to create projection like

```
interface PersonWithExternalDataProjection {
 val uuid: UUID,
 val externalData = externalRestService.getDataBy(uuid)
}
```

Tried @Value but seems it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found that this one works:

```
@get:Value("#{@externalRestService.getDataBy(target.uuid)}")
val externalData: ExternalData
```